# Scores not showing on TOAST

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

I just make a simple Quiz App in android studio the issue in this is Toast not showing the scores. i use condition **index<questions.length** and **if (answer[index] == true) {
score++;
}** someone help me that what is the issue in it?

```
 Button yes ,no;
        TextView tvtxt, result;
        String[] questions={"Java is made in 1992?","Java has abstract classes,","saiyaf born in 1221",
        "jadoons are pathan", "pakistan is super power","Karachi is biggest city of pakistan"};
        Boolean [] answer={false,true,false,true,false,true};
        int score=0;
        int index=0;

    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (index <questions.length) {
    
                        if (answer[index] == true) {
                            score++;
                        }
                        index++;
                        if (index<questions.length){
                            tvtxt.setText(questions[index]);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your score"+score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        }
                    }
    
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESTART APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
    
            });
            no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (index<questions.length) {
    
                        if (answer[index] == false) {
                            score++;
                        }
                        index++;
                        if (index<questions.length){
                            tvtxt.setText(questions[index]);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your score"+score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESTART APP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Debug your application and take a look at what happens. To me, there's no obvious problem.

Comment: Nothing I can see wrong with the code. If the code executes and the questions are showing up correctly, I am surprised that the Toasts both do not show up.

Comment: @f1sh same I'm also confused. but toast really not showing the scores

Comment: When do you want to display a toast for the score? Every time a button is clicked? Or after all questions done?

Comment: I've the impression that your if-else are messed up but you know what you want to do so you need to debug

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the Toast string?

```
String.format("Your score %d", score)
```

or maybe something like

```
"Your score $score"
```